# Preg_match for only title

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have this function which gives me the title of URL pages.

```
function getTitle($url)
        {
            //We cache the URLs
            $pages = cache()->remember('key-'.$url, now()->addDay(1), fn() => file_get_contents($url));
            $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $pages, $match) ? $match[1] : null;
            return $title;
        }
```

And its blade template :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid bg-light-grey-3 p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>
                Plan du Site
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <table>
        @foreach ($data as $node)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href={{ str_replace(' ', '%20', $thisurl = $node->textContent)}}>{{ getTitle($thisurl) }}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

It works for some URL when the actual title is in the < title > but not for others because, in this case, the main title would actually be the < h1 > tag.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ymIZ.png)

How do I use preg_match (or something else) to get the right titles for my pages ?

Comment: Not quite following, why are you creating a function to get the titles, when you can define the title within the blade with a variable, passed from the route? Your main issue seems to be that the sites have different uses of titles. So, what is it you're after? There is title, meta_title and so on. But H1 is not an title in the same way.

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you believe differentiates the title/h1 "titles" as right & wrong. String length of one being longer than the other, a matching text compared to something, or other conditions. I also recommend looking at the [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension to grab the `title` and `h1` nodes to obtain the element's text content of the nodes to determine which you want instead of Regex which won't be able to satisfy every possible pattern.